# VBA: Trying to make code that executes a formula down the line to retrieve data from another worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a VBA code that pulls data from another worksheet via an index match array function (because it needs to satisfy two variables). Basically, I have a source worksheet (Worksheet 1) that is populated with data, and then my main worksheet (Worksheet 2) will pull the data given the criteria to make sure the numbers match up correctly.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

[image]

The formula that I want to replicate down Column G is an index match array function for 2 criteria:

{=INDEX($C$4:$C$7,MATCH(1,(F4=$B$4:$B$7)*(E4=$A$4:$A$7),0))}

Of course there might be a better way to retrieve "Salary" given the 2 criteria ("Country" and "Name") so I am open to those suggestions as well.

EDIT: I wish for this code to be dynamic so that if new rows of data are added, the formula will still replicate down for all rows.

Comment: Did you try using the macro recorder by chance?

Comment: The ideas that come to mind are how to use adodb (sql) and how to solve it without using it.

Comment: I have not. I should have also mentioned that I wish for this code to be dynamic in case rows of data get added. Would the macro recorder work for this?

Comment: Well it would get you started in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Using array functions slows down your computer and makes you unable to run Excel files at some point.
Using the Dictionary is convenient.

```
Sub test()
    Dim wsS As Worksheet
    Dim wsM As Worksheet
    Dim vDB, vResult
    Dim Dic As Object 'Dictionary
    Dim rngResult As Range
    Dim i As Long, s As String

    Set wsS = Sheets("Source")
    Set wsM = Sheets("Main")

    Set Dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    vDB = wsS.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    Set rngResult = wsM.Range("a1").CurrentRegion
    vResult = rngResult

    For i = 2 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        s = vDB(i, 1) & "," & vDB(i, 2)
        If Dic.Exists(s) Then
        Else
            Dic.Add s, vDB(i, 3)
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 2 To UBound(vResult, 1)
        s = vResult(i, 1) & "," & vResult(i, 2)
        vResult(i, 3) = Dic.Item(s)
    Next i
    rngResult = vResult
End Sub
```